# AxWindowsMediaPlayer poor performance

Tags: c#, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

The AxWindowsMediaPlayer control when embedded in a C# winform gets choppy playback.

The only time it plays smoothly is when it is in fullscreen mode.

How can I get the performance of the fullscreen mode all the time?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out.

Had [`windowlessVideo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564092(v=vs.85).aspx) set to `true` which made it render directly onto the winform which caused a loss in quality.